# TCC issue: libtcc1.a not found

Tags: tcc

I am trying to have some fun with TCC, but there seams to be a problem:

```
magniff@/home/magniff/Downloads/tcc-0.9.26> ./tcc examples/ex1.c -Iinclude -Llib
tcc: error: file '/usr/local/lib/tcc/libtcc1.a' not found
```

but

```
magniff@/home/magniff/Downloads/tcc-0.9.26> ls lib -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 magniff magniff   15492 Mar 17 19:12 libtcc1.a  <-- this guy
-rw-r--r--. 1 magniff magniff 1411822 Mar 17 19:12 libtcc.a
```

Symlink is not an option either.
It seams to be a common TCC issue, but solution always looks like some custom hack.
Any ideas?

I am using fedora 20

Comment: It seams that TCC is not able to use symlinks, so you need actually copy the lib.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that TCC is not able to use symlinks, so you need to actually copy the lib.

(originally posted by [the asker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1805399/alexander-koshkin) as a comment)

Answer (score -1):

To run `tcc` without installing do:

```bash
./tcc -L./ ./hello_world.c
```

By default the `libtcc1.a` is dumped into the project directory so `-L./` just uses the current folder for finding linked libraries.